# List of tuples of vectors --> two matrices

Tags: python, numpy, tuples

In Python, I have a list of tuples, each of them containing two nx1 vectors.

```py
data = [(np.array([0,0,3]), np.array([0,1])),
        (np.array([1,0,4]), np.array([1,1])),
        (np.array([2,0,5]), np.array([2,1]))]
```

Now, I want to split this list into two matrices, with the vectors as columns. 
So I'd want:

```py
x = np.array([[0,1,2],
              [0,0,0],
              [3,4,5]])

y = np.array([[0,1,2],
              [1,1,1]])
```

Right now, I have the following:

```py
def split(data):
    x,y = zip(*data)

    np.asarray(x)
    np.asarray(y)
    x.transpose()
    y.transpose()

    return (x,y)
```

This works fine, but I was wondering whether a cleaner method exists, which doesn't use the zip(*) function and/or doesn't require to convert and transpose the x and y matrices.

Comment: For the first step, I don't think there's a way around looping or using zip to split the first arrays from the second, as the inner arrays are unevenly sized

Comment: `np.stack(x, 1)` is a little shorter.  You are starting with a heterogenous structure with arrays of size 3 and 2.  `x,y=zip(*data)` is a clean expression for rearranging the list into to two more homeogenous ones.  Don't dismiss list operations as 'unclean'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for pure entertainment, since I'd go with the `zip` solution if I were to do what you're trying to do.

But a way without `zipping` would be `vstack` along your axis 1.

```
a = np.array(data) 
f = lambda axis: np.vstack(a[:, axis]).T 

x,y = f(0), f(1)
```

---

```
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5]])

>>> y
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple. This also happens when I use def instead of lambda.

How do I fix this? Just a[:][axis] doesn't work, as "all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly".

Comment: @JonasDeSchouwer it's not `a[:][axis]`, but `a[:, axis]`

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the best elements of all previously proposed methods, I think it's best as follows*:

```py
def split(data):
    x,y = zip(*data)         #splits the list into two tuples of 1xn arrays, x and y

    x = np.vstack(x[:]).T    #stacks the arrays in x vertically and transposes the matrix
    y = np.vstack(y[:]).T    #stacks the arrays in y vertically and transposes the matrix

    return (x,y)
```

<sup>* this is a snippet of my code</sup>